# Show toast when the url changes in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to show a simple message when a user is logged in I am trying to use this method:

```
this.$router.push('/dashboard', () => {
  console.log('hiiiii')
  this.$bvToast.toast('Welcome!', {
    title: 'Message',
    solid: true,
    variant: 'success'
  })
})
```

I can see `console.log('hiiiii')` is executed but I dont see the toast showing in the screen, I thought that onComplete shall execute after the url is changed or I am missing something ?

I am using nuxtjs v.2.15.7 with vue-router v.3.5.1

Comment: What router version are you using? It might be that this.$bvToas is not the right scoped this here ...

Comment: In 2.2.0+, optionally provide onComplete and onAbort callbacks to router.push or router.replace as the 2nd and 3rd arguments. These callbacks will be called when the navigation either successfully completed (after all async hooks are resolved), or aborted (navigated to the same route, or to a different route before current navigation has finished), respectively. In 3.1.0+, you can omit the 2nd and 3rd parameter and router.push/router.replace will return a promise instead if Promises are supported.

Comment: try  this.$router.push('/dashboard').then(() => { console.log('hiiiii') })  and then try calling the toast in then( ) block

Comment: hi @mahatmanich, none of the solutions worked :(

Comment: mhhh where do you call the router push? can you provide the larger scope?

Comment: also, this.$bvToast works otherwise?

Comment: @mahatmanich if its outside the callback method it works just fine

Comment: Have you tried putting your call in `nextTick()`